Scilab API компиляция C++
Можете подсказать, почему при компиляции не видит заголовочный файл scilab.hpp?
Правильно ли я вообще используя Scilab API на C++? Цель программы - складывание, вычитание, умножение и деление чисел с помощью Scilab API на C++.
Сам код:
#include <iostream>
#include "scilab.hpp"

int main() {
    // Создание экземпляра объекта Scilab
    Scilab scilab;

    // Запуск сессии Scilab
    if (!scilab.Start()) {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка при запуске Scilab." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Переменные для хранения чисел и результата
    double num1, num2, result;

    // Ввод чисел
    std::cout << "Введите первое число: ";
    std::cin >> num1;
    std::cout << "Введите второе число: ";
    std::cin >> num2;

    // Сложение
    result = scilab.Add(num1, num2);
    std::cout << "Сумма: " << result << std::endl;

    // Вычитание
    result = scilab.Subtract(num1, num2);
    std::cout << "Разность: " << result << std::endl;

    // Умножение
    result = scilab.Multiply(num1, num2);
    std::cout << "Произведение: " << result << std::endl;

    // Деление
    if (num2 != 0) {
        result = scilab.Divide(num1, num2);
        std::cout << "Частное: " << result << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Деление на ноль невозможно." << std::endl;
    }

    // Завершение сессии Scilab
    scilab.Stop();

    return 0;
}


Компиляция:
g++ -o 1 1.cpp -I/usr/include/scilab/ -lscicall_scilab -lapi_scilab -lscilab



"не видит заголовочный файл scilab.hpp" - в скришноте ошибка другая. А еще выкладывать ошибки в виде скриншотов - плохая идея.

Забавно, что имена файлов (расширения) разные в тексте и на скриншоте...

Перепутал изображения, но суть все такая же. Правильно ли я вообще компилирую программу? Ключи компиляции правильные? Не работал ранее с Scilab API, но вывод следующий
1.cpp:2:10: fatal error: scilab.hpp: Нет такого файла или каталога
2 | #include "scilab.hpp"
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
